# Non-recursive formula for discrete function that follows a recursive pattern

Tags: sequences-and-series, recursion

$f$ is a sequence of numbers and $v$ is the sequence of the difference between the consecutive terms of $f$.

For example, if
$f = 1,   3,   4,   7,   5$, then
$v =   2,   1,   3,   {-2}$.

$f$ is $0\mathrm{-indexed}$, i.e., $1$ is the $0\mathrm{th}$ element of $f$.

$v$ is $1\mathrm{-indexed}$, i.e., $2$ is the $1\mathrm{st}$ element of $v$. But the $0\mathrm{th}$ element of $v$ can be taken to be $0$ or any other arbitrary number.

Here is the original problem I am trying to solve:

Given $f_0 = 0$ and $v = 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, \text{...}$ $v$ is periodic and has a period of $4$.

Find formulas for $f_i$ and use it to calculate $f_{12}$ and $f_{63}$.

Here is a formula I came up with ($v$ is $1\mathrm{-indexed}$ but $v_0$ can be assigned a value of desired):

$$v_0 = 0$$
$$v_1 = v_3 = 1$$
$$v_2 = 2$$
$$v_x = v_{\text{(x mod 4)}}$$

The formula for $v_x$ can be used in the formula of $f_x$:

$$f_0 = 0$$
$$f_1 = 1$$
$$f_2 = 3$$
$$f_3 = f_4 = 4$$
$$f_x = f_{x-1} + v_x$$

The last rule simply takes the previous $f$ and adds the current $v$ to it.

All this works fine but the trouble is doing the recursive calculation on hand for $f_x$ can quickly become overwhelming. Questions similar to these are expected to be on the exam where calculators won't be allowed.

Can a simpler, hand calculation friendly formula be found for $f_x?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can be found
$$f_{x+4}=f_x+v_{x+1}+v_{x+2}+v_{x+3}+v_{x+4} $$
Now, $v_{x+1}+v_{x+2}+v_{x+3}+v_{x+4} = v_0+v_1+v_2+v_3 = 4$, so that $f_{x+4}=f_x+4$.

For example:
$$f_{4k}=f_{4(k-1)}+4=...=f_{4(k-m)}+4m = ... = f_0+4k=4k $$
Similar can be told about $f_{4k+1}$, $f_{4k+2}$, $f_{4k+3}$. We are arrive at a form that's easy for calculations.

Comment: Can you please explain your point on arithmetic progression?

Comment: @AbhishekKumar I tried to edit my post, to not give you a direct answer, but so that my point is clearer.